# How to perform minor upgrades with ceph-deploy?

Tags: upgrade, ceph, nautilus

I have a cluster runnin nautilus v14.2.4 and want to upgrade it to the latest nautilus version.

Is this posible with ceph-deploy?

I see the package upgrade in apt, but can't find any documenatation for how to do the upgrade on nautilus.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was sufficient to just run apt update && apt upgrade on all the hosts and after that restart the entire cluster in the following order:

1. Monitors
2. Managers
3. Mds
4. All OSDs

Answer (score 0):

`ceph-deploy` is not really supported anymore and its functionality might be broken. I think it still is able to perform the basic tasks but I wouldn't rely on it. I haven't tried that myself but one way would be to change the repos (if necessary) for newer packages and run `ceph-deploy install --release nautilus <NODE>` and see if that works. If updates are applied you can continue with the rest, if not you'll have to run the update manually on each node.

Comment: Will give it a try and report back. Thanks for the info.